# Incomplete Definition of Type (struct )

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, struct

I tried many times to fix the error "`Incomplete Definition of Type of struct *` ,please can you help me to find the problem and fix it ?

Any advice on this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
struct mypoint;
typedef struct mypoint {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void setRandomPoint(struct mypoint *a, int min, int max)
{
    do {
        a->x = rand();

    } while (a->x > max || a->x < min);
    do
    {
        a->y = rand();
    } while (a->y > max || a->y < min);


}
int main()
{
    struct myPoint point;
    int min = 0, max = 0;
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (min >= max)
    {
        printf("Enter min:");
        scanf("%d", &min);
        printf("Enter max:");
        scanf("%d", &max);
    }
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        setRandomPoint(&point, min, max);
        printf("%d. point.x=%d, point.y=%d\n", i + 1, point.x, point.y);
    }
    printf("Finish.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

please anyone can help me plz ?

Comment: You haven't added concrete statements around the code, just sentences so SO would let you post. You should post the error, on which line, and what have you tried to fix it.

Comment: `struct myPoint point` -> `struct mypoint point`.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

Add a name to your `typedef`'ed struct :

```
typedef struct mypoint {
    int x;
    int y;
} myPoint;
```

Judging from your statement :

```
struct myPoint point;
```

I guess the name you want to give is `myPoint`. Right now, you have forgotten to give it a name so `myPoint` does not exist.

---

***Also note*** that the declaration :

```
struct myPoint point;
```

which you are now using is wrong, even if you give a name to your `typedef`'ed struct. After giving a name, you can either access your `struct` by using :

```
myPoint point;
```

or :

```
struct mypoint point;
```

Comment: anyway it would be `struct mypoint point;` or just `myPoint point;`

Answer (score 3):

```
struct mypoint;
```

This is a forward declaration. You tell the compiler that there exists a struct called `mypoint` but for now the compiler can't know what that struct contains. This is a struct of *incomplete type*, meaning that somewhere later you have to complete it with a full definition.

---

```
typedef struct mypoint {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

This isn't a correct way to define a struct. If you omit the typedef, then you would get a struct that's defined with a "tag" called `mypoint`. That would be enough to use said struct, even though you'll have to refer to it as `struct mypoint` everywhere.

You should only use `typedef` when making a new struct *type*. Such a type needs a type name, which is typed at the end. The above code snippet is missing the type name, which is why you get the compiler error.

Correct code:

```
typedef struct mypoint { // struct "tag"
    int x;
    int y;
} mypoint; // type name
```

Note that the struct tag and type name exist in different name spaces, so they can actually have the same name. Most often both of these are not used at the same time. Common styles is to either use `typedef struct {...} mypoint;` or `struct mypoint {...};`.

There's a bit of a style war about what's preferred. The Linux camp prefer the latter style and therefore types out `struct` everywhere in the code. While pretty much everyone else prefers to use typedef. The arguments for or against either style are subjective and there is no obvious right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In `typedefed struct` you forgot the name `myPoint`

```
typedef struct mypoint {
    ...
    ...
} myPoint;
```

Also, later use `myPoint point;` only as you already defined `myPoint` as struct. So no need to use `struct` again

Also, you can get rid of the statement `struct mypoint;`